# Jquery - How to get elements in a list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
                <li class="shop-currencies">
                    <a href="#" id="EUR" data-currency="EUR">€</a>
                    <a href="#" id="GBP" data-currency="GBP">£</a>
                    <a href="#" id="USD" data-currency="USD">$</a>
                    <a href="#" id="ZAR" data-currency="ZAR" class="current">R</a>
                </li>
```

When an item is clicked I want to set the class to the clicked item and get the ID of the item clicked. This is what I have so far:

```
$('.shop-currencies').click(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    alert(id);

    /**
     * Remove the classes from the currency elements
     */
    $('.shop-currencies').find('a').each(function(e) {
       $(this).removeClass();
    });

    /**
     * Set the class of the clicked element
     */
    $( '#' + id).addClass('current');



});
```

The ID is being returned as 'undefined' How do I get the ID of the clicked link?

Thanks

Comment: Please note that your bookmark anchors (`href="#"`) will cause the page to spring to the top if it has scrolled at all, so also add `e.preventDefault();` to any solution you choose :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options, Milind Anantwar has one, the other is to use the originally clicked element, which is passed to the event as a `target` property on the event argument. You can also simplify your code a lot. Please note that your bookmark anchors will cause the page to spring to the top, so also add         `e.preventDefault();` to any solution you choose:

```
$('.shop-currencies').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a', this).removeClass('current');   // remove related anchor current class
    $(e.target).addClass('current');
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5Lsuazvt/

The one downside to this is that clicking inside `.shop-currencies`, but not on a currency link, will clear the current selection. Because of this you are better off targetting the links instead:

```
$('.shop-currencies a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('current');   // remove related anchor current class
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5Lsuazvt/1/

Which can be reduced to one line:

```
$('.shop-currencies a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5Lsuazvt/2/

**Saving the best for last**

And one last point... It is more efficient (but hardly noticeable) to add a single delegated event handler, instead of attaching 4 seperate handlers:

```
$('.shop-currencies').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5Lsuazvt/3/

**Final thoughts:**

The IDs on the links are unnecessary if you have an appropriate *this* available. You can remove them from the HTML. You have the currency value you require in `data-currency` attributes, so you could use it like this:

```
$('.shop-currencies').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
    alert($(this).data('currency'));
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5Lsuazvt/7/

Comment: A nice explanation, thank you for the tips and the effort. I am marking this as the answer as it is the most comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach click handler to child anchor element :

```
$('.shop-currencies a').click(function() {

var id = $(this).attr('id');

alert(id);

 /**
 * Remove the classes from the currency elements
 */
   $('.shop-currencies').find('a').not(this).removeClass('smclass')
 /**
 * Add class to current elements
 */
   $(this).addClass('smclass')
});
```

Comment: I'd say it's better to use 
`$('.shop-currencies').on('click', 'a' function() { ... });`
With this modification your code will be more compatible with future versions of jQuery and will work with anchors created dynamically.

Comment: And why so. there is no need to delegate the event.

Answer (score 0):

your click, is attach to li instead of each a tag 
so do `$('a').click();`instead

Answer (score 0):

Shortest and fastest answer

```
$('.shop-currencies > a').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings('a').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

The code pen link is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbdRPm), you can play with the code your self

Comment: Never say `shortest and fastest` as a) it is not the shortest/fastest way to do this code and b) you are unlikely to care how fast this simple operation is as the speed differences are tiny :) (F.Y.I. a delegated event handler will be faster to connect and chaining your `siblings` after `addClass` will make it shorter :>)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.shop-currencies a').each(function() {
 $(this).on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('.shop-currencies a').removeClass("current");
  $(this).addClass('current');
  alert(id);
 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nj37g5rm/8/

Comment: Why introduce an `each` when jQuery does that automatically? Just realised this does not even target the anchors, so will not work at all. :(

Comment: he has an each on his code. Thanks for the down vote. This code I wrote works perfectly. if you want you can argue it but my answer is correct for his question no need for down votes.

Comment: ye typo, forgot the a tag, now updated. No need for big times.

Comment: The `remove` is still incorrect. Please use a JSFiddle or similar to test your answers. Then it will be obvious if it works (or not). Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5Lsuazvt/4/

Comment: there you go the jsfiddle in the answer.

Comment: Still broken. You can see how if you add styling: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/nj37g5rm/1/

Comment: hey the guy wants a current class on the clicked link only and he wants the ID value to be printed in the alert. And that's what my code does. Nothing wrong with what I did.

Comment: rigth ye I had to target the a tag when removing the class. updated.

Comment: Finally :) I will remove my downvote (as it now works), but cannot upvote as you should not use an `each` to connect identical handlers to multiple items in jQuery. That is unnecessary.

Comment: damn me.. lol..was an easy answer and forgot stupid thingies with typos. Anyhow, why is it .each not necessary? Doing .find as you do might be quicker but .each is just fine no?

Comment: `each` is a waste of time & code-size when you can just have `$('.shop-currencies a').click(function() {`. See the other answers for various, shorter/faster alternatives. :)

Comment: i thougth with new jQuery we had to use on.("click".. no? And ye saw the other answers but they are incomplete as they do not get the ID as the quetsion asks :)

Comment: The ID was only used to select *the element the element was clicked* :) That of course is a complete waste of time if you have an appropriate *this*. You need to figure out the intended aim and not copy the OPs mistakes :) ID's are not even needed for the desired result.

Comment: actually he does say "AND get the ID of the item clicked. " anyhow, he got the answer ;)

Comment: who knows..he didn't say it..maybe he needs it for something else tho :)

Comment: As the currency meta data value is in `data-currency`, I would drop the IDs (if only to avoid ID-clutter on the page) and use `.data("currency")`. I updated my own answer to include this suggestion.